# iTextSharp: Any support for dotnet core (netstandard1.6)?

Tags: itext, .net-core, .net-standard-1.6

I've been using iTextSharp with regular dotnet applications for a while now. We're interested in using it with dotnet core. But it seems that the library is still not supported on the new dotnet core platform:

Package iTextSharp 5.5.10 is not compatible with netstandard1.6

Do you plan to support dotnet core in a future release?

Comment: there's a non official port here https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp.LGPLv2.Core/

Answer (score 18):

For the record: I was an employee at iText Software at the time I wrote the following statement.

As of 2016, `.NET Core` and the related `UWP` standard are not supported by any iText projects. We have done investigations into both these new technologies and have found that there are significant issues with supporting them, because of drastic modifications in certain components of the `.NET Core` software stack. You can read https://stackoverflow.com/a/34612369/2065017 for more details about my initial investigation into `UWP`; the problems with `.NET Core` are very similar.

`.NET Core` will be supported, it will probably only be in our new project iText 7, which is not backwards compatible to iText 5 (also known as iTextSharp). The reason for this is that iText 5 is now only on maintenance, i.e. bugfix releases, as it is being supplanted by iText 7 in the user community.

iText 7 for .NET (meaning only the `.NET Framework`) is actually an automated port of iText 7 for Java, using the tool `Sharpen`. This takes away the possibility of many nasty lingering bugs that used to pop up in iTextSharp 5 because of porting omissions or errors. We are currently looking if there is any way to duplicate this workflow for `.NET Core` so that we can support this without having to do manual porting and manual maintenance. I regret to inform you that we have not found any such tool yet, so we may have to investigate building a `Sharpen`-like tool ourselves. This is currently, perhaps unsurprisingly, not our biggest priority as a company.

## EDIT (July 2020)

I am no longer an employee at iText Software, but I know that .NET Standard 1.6 and up have been supported since iText 7.1.1 for .NET, which was released in early 2018, thus any relatively recent version of UWP and of .NET Core are also supported.

Comment: What's about netstandard 2.0?

Comment: Yes, I'm also very interessted by .net core/standard 2.0

Comment: .NET Standard 1.6 and up are supported (experimental support, so not thoroughly tested) since iText 7.1.1.

Comment: Any update on this since with the recent announcement of .NET 5, .NET Framework is officially declared dead?

Comment: HI @blagae, I can see above post is too old, so do we have any new updates on itext7 to support .Net Core framework ?