# Xamarian Cross Platform iTextsharp package installation error

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am unable to install any package in my project. I need `ITextSharp` package to install in my project.

but I got some error:

```
Install-Package : NU1202: Package iTextSharp-LGPL-BouncyCastle 4.1.6 is not compatible with xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0). Package iTextSharp-LGPL-BouncyCastle 4.1.6 supports: - net (.NETFramework,Version=v0.0) - net20 (.NETFramework,Version=v2.0) At line:1 char:1 + Install-Package iTextSharp-LGPL-BouncyCastle -Version 4.1.6 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : NU1202: Package iTextSharp 5.5.13 is not compatible with xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0). Package iTextSharp 5.5.13 supports: net (.NETFramework,Version=v0.0) At line:1 char:1 + Install-Package iTextSharp-LGPL-BouncyCastle -Version 4.1.6 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : NU1202: Package BouncyCastle 1.7.0 is not compatible with xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0). Package BouncyCastle 1.7.0 supports: - net20 (.NETFramework,Version=v2.0) - net40-client (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client) At line:1 char:1 + Install-Package iTextSharp-LGPL-BouncyCastle -Version 4.1.6 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : NU1202: Package iTextSharp-LGPL-BouncyCastle 4.1.6 is not compatible with xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0) / win. Package iTextSharp-LGPL-BouncyCastle 4.1.6 supports: - net (.NETFramework,Version=v0.0) - net20 (.NETFramework,Version=v2.0) At line:1 char:1 + Install-Package iTextSharp-LGPL-BouncyCastle -Version 4.1.6 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : NU1202: Package BouncyCastle 1.7.0 is not compatible with xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0) / win. Package BouncyCastle 1.7.0 supports: - net20 (.NETFramework,Version=v2.0) - net40-client (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client) At line:1 char:1 + Install-Package iTextSharp-LGPL-BouncyCastle -Version 4.1.6 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : NU1202: Package iTextSharp 5.5.13 is not compatible with xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0) / win. Package iTextSharp 5.5.13 supports: net (.NETFramework,Version=v0.0) At line:1 char:1 + Install-Package iTextSharp-LGPL-BouncyCastle -Version 4.1.6 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : NU1202: Package iTextSharp-LGPL-BouncyCastle 4.1.6 is not compatible with xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0) / win-x64. Package iTextSharp-LGPL-BouncyCastle 4.1.6 supports: - net (.NETFramework,Version=v0.0) - net20 (.NETFramework,Version=v2.0) At line:1 char:1 + Install-Package iTextSharp-LGPL-BouncyCastle -Version 4.1.6 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : NU1202: Package BouncyCastle 1.7.0 is not compatible with xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0) / win-x64. Package BouncyCastle 1.7.0 supports: - net20 (.NETFramework,Version=v2.0) - net40-client (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client) At line:1 char:1 + Install-Package iTextSharp-LGPL-BouncyCastle -Version 4.1.6 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : NU1202: Package iTextSharp 5.5.13 is not compatible with xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0) / win-x64. Package iTextSharp 5.5.13 supports: net (.NETFramework,Version=v0.0) At line:1 char:1 + Install-Package iTextSharp-LGPL-BouncyCastle -Version 4.1.6 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : NU1202: Package iTextSharp-LGPL-BouncyCastle 4.1.6 is not compatible with xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0) / win-x86. Package iTextSharp-LGPL-BouncyCastle 4.1.6 supports: - net (.NETFramework,Version=v0.0) - net20 (.NETFramework,Version=v2.0) At line:1 char:1 + Install-Package iTextSharp-LGPL-BouncyCastle -Version 4.1.6 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : NU1202: Package BouncyCastle 1.7.0 is not compatible with xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0) / win-x86. Package BouncyCastle 1.7.0 supports: - net20 (.NETFramework,Version=v2.0) - net40-client (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client) At line:1 char:1 + Install-Package iTextSharp-LGPL-BouncyCastle -Version 4.1.6 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : NU1202: Package iTextSharp 5.5.13 is not compatible with xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0) / win-x86. Package iTextSharp 5.5.13 supports: net (.NETFramework,Version=v0.0) At line:1 char:1 + Install-Package iTextSharp-LGPL-BouncyCastle -Version 4.1.6 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'HomeApplication_V4.iOS'. At line:1 char:1 + Install-Package iTextSharp-LGPL-BouncyCastle -Version 4.1.6 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand Any suggestion about my project.

Please give me suggestion. what I need to do about xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0) / win. I have tried with Itextsharp V4.17 also but error remain same.
```

Any ideas about how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done a lot of research and I found some useful links for you:

[iTextSharp: Any support for dotnet core (netstandard1.6)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40236194/itextsharp-any-support-for-dotnet-core-netstandard1-6)

***So the problem that .NET Standard is not supported by iTextSharp***. If you still want to use iTextSharp in your project, you need to use Xamarin Port. You can download the source code for iTextSharp and copy-paste into a new Xamarin Class Library project in Visual Studio.

I found that some one has done this before, for example: [Xam.iTextSharpLGPL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.iTextSharpLGPL/). But the problem is that this is based on an ancient version of iText (released on Jul 7th 2009) that will never get updates or bug fixes.

iText Software has published a Xamarin port of iText 7, which will continue to get updates. **I think you should use iText7 instead.** I have tested on my side, I could install iText7 without any issue.

Hope this will help you.

Thanks